# Check if an array contais a time - Perl

Tags: perl

How do I check if an array contains a time value? I've tried checking like this:

```
if ( @time =~ /$_:$_:$_/)
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas?

P.S.: The time is given like this: **HH:MM:SS**

Comment: Your code does not have an array. and `$_` will be interpolated to whatever its value is in your pattern.

Comment: Just corrected this

Comment: You can't just change `$` to `@`. That code will test the *number of elements in `@time`* as a string against a regex built from the contents of `$_` and a couple of colons. If you never make a better attempt than that to solve your own problems then you will always be a programmer who gets others to do their work.

Comment: That it's not what is in the code itself. The code is: `$tableData{$date[$count_date]}{$company[$aux2]}{$ip[$aux2]}{$info[$aux3]}` this is just a simplification

Comment: Good job on simplifying. However, there's no array there. There might be an array reference, but we don't know. In any case, if there's a list of things involved, you have to iterate.

Comment: Yes, this is inside some `for` loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Matching the time

To check for `HH:MM:SS` with a regular expression match, the simplest pattern would be

```
/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/
```

If you only want this, add anchors for start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string.

```
/^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/
```

If you want to make sure that your digits are only `0` to `9` and not digits from any script, use a character group.

```
/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/
```

If you also want to make sure the time is a valid time, things get more complicated.

You might want to read [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). The [tag wiki on Regular Expressions here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) has a lot of useful information and links to tools as well.

---

### On arrays and scalars

However, there is no *array* in the code you've shown. In Perl, a variable with a `$` as its *sigil* is called a *scalar* and represents a single value. That's the only thing you can pattern match against. An array would start with an `@` symbol.

What you can do is match against every element in your array. For that, you have to *iterate* the array.

A very verbose way to do that would be:

```
my $matches;
foreach my $time (@times) {
    ++$matches if $time =~ m/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/;
}
```

A more Perlish way would be to use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

```
my $matches = grep { m/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/ } @times;
```

This makes use of the fact that the list returned by `grep` will be converted to its number of elements in *scalar context*. If all you want is to know whether any of the elements matched, this is enough.

---

### What your code did

The `$_` variable is called the *topic* in Perl, and often contains some kind of default value for certain operators, if no other value is specified. Depending on where in your program you used your line of code, you are matching the number of elements in `@time` (because of scalar context, see above) against a pattern built up of the content of `$_` and colons.

```
if (
  @time  # number of elements in array @times
  =~     # because this operator forces scalar context
  /
    $_   # value of $_ based on surrounding code, or undef
    :    # a literal colon
    $_   # see above
    :    # a literal colon
    $_   # see above
  /x     # ( I added /x to allow comments so this compiles)
) { ... }
```

Comment: What does the `$` at the end of the `/^[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$/` expression means?

Comment: @JoãoV. `$` is the anchor for the end of the string. Please refer to a tool like https://regex101.com for explanations of what patterns mean. :)

Comment: @JoãoV. see my update. That should clear up all your questions and hopefully give you a few new ones, which will lead to reading documentation ;)

Comment: `\z` means end of string. `$` means something different, and shouldn't be used here.